# what's causing jekyll to throw a "undefined method `require_from_bundler'" error on any command?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, jekyll

I'm working on a jekyll site on Ubuntu 15.04 and when i try `jekyll serve` (or any other jekyll command, with or without sudo) i receive the following:

```
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/jekyll-3.1.2/bin/jekyll:9:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `require_from_bundler' for     Jekyll::PluginManager:Class (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
```

I have worked on jekyll sites on this computer recently without this issue, and I'm not certain how the configuration changed to generate this error. I've tried `gem uninstall jekyll` and reinstalling it, same issue happens. I'm not a Ruby dev and I'm a bit at a loss for how to troubleshoot this.

Comment: When you uninstall/reinstall `jekyll` which version is installed?  3.1.2?

Comment: `gem list` produces: `jekyll (3.1.2, 2.2.0)`

Comment: ok i ran `sudo gem uninstall jekyll --version 3.1.2` and that cleared up the above error, now i'm getting a page of dependency issues such as: `/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in 'to_specs': Could not find 'pygments.rb' (~> 0.6.0) - did find: [pygments.rb-0.5.4] (Gem::LoadError)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I suggest you to run Jekyll with [Bundler](https://bundler.io), which is an awesome dependency manager. It will make sure you have all the gems you need.

**1st**. Uninstall Jekyll 2.2.0. This version is too old and requires Python to run some dependencies. Jekyll 3.x does not require Python anymore.

So, run `sudo gem uninstall jekyll --version 2.2.0`. (or `gem uninstall jekyll -v 2.2.0`)

**2nd**. Now, install Bundler:

`gem install bundler` (or `sudo gem install bundler`)

**3rd.** Add a `Gemfile` (don't give it any extension) to your site root with the following content:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem 'jekyll', '3.1.2'
```

This will make sure you will have installed Jekyll 3.1.2 and all its dependencies.

If you will deploy your site to GitHub, the Gemfile must be different:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem 'github-pages'
```

This will include the Jekyll version running at GitHub pages at the time.

**4th.** Using the terminal, `cd path/to/path` to your site root and run `bundle install` there. Bundler will install all the dependencies for you and create a new file called `Gemfile.lock`, which will have a list of all dependencies installed for that project.

**5th.** Run `bundle exec jekyll serve`

Done!

---

NOTE 1: I recommend you to use Jekyll 3.0.3, as I think it's better then 3.1.2 (it seems there are some bugs on 3.1.2 which don't have in 3.0.3). Anyway, opinion based tip - it's up to you.

NOTE 2: If you don't have openssl installed to your computer, replace the protocol in your Gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
```

replace for

```
source "http://rubygems.org"
```

For reference:

- [Jekyll 2x-to-3x](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/upgrading/2-to-3/)
- [Jekyll on GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-your-pages-site-locally-with-jekyll/)

That's it! Hope to have helped!

Comment: Thanks for this thorough walk-through. However, I've attempted to `sudo gem uninstall jekyll` and receive permissions error for a file that doesn't appear to exist: `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/bin directory.` any insights? i'm going to try installing RVM next.

Comment: i was able to use Bundler without uninstalling the old version of jekyll. so now `bundle exec jekyll serve` works. thanks for your help!

Comment: I think you'll need to open the terminal with admin rights to uninstall Jekyll 2.2.0. Anyway, I'm glad to have helped. :)